# Access from UserControl's properties to all of a inside control's properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, user-controls

So, i made a "custom textbox". The UserControl is just a Grid with a Rectangle and a TextBox, some code behind just colores the rectangle if the mouse is over and colores the text of the TextBox is it's keyboard focussed. I want to have acces to all the properties a TextBox has without having to manualy wire every one up by setting dependency properties and then binding them up in XAML. Is there any way to just let the TextBox properties to be accesible fron XAML?

Comment: You need to inherit the "custom textbox" from "Textbox" class to access all properties without wire up.

Comment: Perhaps you don't even need to create a derived control. Try to write an appropriate ControlTemplate for TextBox. See [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Give your `TextBox` in `UserControl` name:

```
<TextBox x:Name="uscTbx" Text={Binding toSomething}/>
```

In code behind of your `UserControl` define a property:

```
public TextBox UscTexBox { get { return uscTbx; }}
```

In XAML of another windows you can acces the properties of your TextBox:

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="usc1"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=UscTexBox.Text, ElementName=usc1}"/>
```